# Body NULL NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou começando com nodejs, porem sempre que tento enviar (email e senha) para a API via POST, os valores digitados sao retornados como NULL.

```
router.post("/users", function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body)
        let query = "INSERT INTO ??(??,??) VALUES (?,?)";
        let table = ["user_login","user_email","user_password", req.body.email, md5(req.body.password)];
        query = mysql.format(query, table);
        console.log(query)
        connection.query(query, function(err, rows){
            if(err){
                res.json({"Error": true, "Message": "Erro ao executar a query do MYSQL"})
            }else{
                res.json({"Error" : false, "Message": "Usuario adicionado!"});
            }
        })
    });


REST.prototype.configureExpress = function(connection){
    let self = this;
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    let router = express.Router();
    app.use('/api', router);

    let rest_router = new rest(router, connection, md5);
    self.startServer();
}
```

Comment: O JSON e content-type no POST são válidos? Geralmente esse problema acontece pela ausência do body parser. Como está seu `app.js`?

Comment: Exatamente, passei a cima a configuracao, app.use(bodyParser.json()); Quando eu envio algo (usando o POSTMAN) eu passo Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Esse trecho está no `app.js`? Aparentemente está usando express, poderia tentar passar direto `app.use(bodyParser.json());` e
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` no app.js, talvez `configureExpress` não esteja sendo chamado..testou isso?

Comment: @LucasCosta sim, ele esta no Server.js, e testei sim, e esta sendo executado

Comment: Sinto muito em ficar fazendo perguntas e pedir testes, mas são as coisas que podem estar causando o problema @RafaelAugusto. Tente colocar `configureExpress` bloco por primeiro de tudo, antes das rotas.

Comment: Ele já esta, coloquei depois so ai no exemplo, mas no codigo ele esta

Comment: Estás a enviar um GET ou um POST? podes mostrar o HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: @Sergio estou enviado POST, usando o POSTMAN para testar a API

Comment: O que dá `console.log(req.body);`?

Comment: @Sergio Vazio "{}", eu consegui recuperar o valor assim req.query.email, mas acho que nao é a forma correta, entao gostaria de conseguir descobrir a fonte do problema.

Comment: Mostra o HTML e JavaScript se houver

Comment: @Sergio nao tenho HTML ou JS, tudo que tenho é o JS da API (Node), os testes que faço é via PostMAN

Comment: Ah, verdade tinhas dito, esqueci. Acho que o postman está a mandar um GET. Tens a certeza que estás a receber um POST?

Comment: Agora que voce falou, ele so insere da maneira que falou a cima, quando eu envio GET, se eu envio post, o valor se mantém vazio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, o erro na verdade era do POSTMAN. so configuracao da forma de passar parametros, ele estava mandando GET, mesmo eu mudando para POST

Comment: Explique melhor como você resolveu o seu problema, e aceite sua própria resposta, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

> No postman, mude os seus `Headers` para `Content-Type: application/json`:

[image: screenshot dos headers do postman]

> Mude no `Body` para `raw`:

[image: screenshot do body do postman]

> E, fazendo o `Post`, a resposta veio:

[image: screenshot da resposta no postman]

Aqui está o código que eu usei para teste - server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser  = require("body-parser");
var app  = express();
var rest = require("./rest.js");
var router = express.Router();
app.use('/api', router);

function REST(){
    var self = this;
    self.configureExpress();
};

REST.prototype.configureExpress = function(connection){
    let self = this;
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    let router = express.Router();
    app.use('/api', router);

    let rest_router = new rest(router, connection);
    self.startServer();
}

REST.prototype.startServer = function() {
      app.listen(3000,function(){
          console.log("servidor trakinas");
      });
}

new REST();
```

E rest.js:

```
function REST_ROUTER(router,connection) {
    var self = this;
    self.handle_routes(router,connection);
}

REST_ROUTER.prototype.handle_routes = function(router,connection) {
    router.get("/bolacha", function(req,res) {
        res.json({"sabor" : "uva"});
    })

    router.post("/bolacha", function(req, res){
        res.send(200, req.body);
    });
}

module.exports = REST_ROUTER;
```

A fonte para essa resposta está [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts).